# Python: how to split a string based on space but keep '\n'?

Tags: python

I want to split a string based on space

```
a = ' girl\n    is'
a.split()
['girl', 'is']
```

I found that after split, the '\n' will also disappear. My desired result is

```
['girl\n', 'is']
```

Then if I used `.splitlines` method, the result returned is also not what I want.

```
a.splitlines(True)
[' girl\n', '    is']
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: `split()` without argument will split your string with any whitespace. If you want to split based on spaces you should pass it to the function. `a.split(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, you should consider using *list comprehensions* (as is mentioned in *[Ursus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48128945/2063361)*)  with `str.split(' ')` as:

```
>>> a = ' girl\n    is'

>>> [word for word in a.split(' ') if word]
['girl\n', 'is']
```

However if you are interested in **functional approach**, you may use [**`filter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) as:

```
>>> list(filter(bool, a.split(' ')))
['girl\n', 'is']
```

Here `a.split(' ')` will split your string based on *space* as *separator* and `filter` *(with bool)* will filter out your empty strings from the list.

---

**Issue with your code**

As the Python's [`str.split` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) says:

- if *separator* is not passed:

  > or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace**. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].
- if *separator* is passed:

  > **consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings**. Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns [''].

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
[s for s in a.split(' ') if s]
['girl\n', 'is']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions in order to split on any *sequences* of *horizontal* whitespace (including e.g. tabs), but not vertical:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[^\S\n\r]+', a.strip())
['girl\n', 'is']

# [^...]: not any of ...
# \S:     non whitespace
# \n, \r: line breaking white space 
# [^\S\n\r]+: one or more non-space or non-line-breaking space
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand:

```
b=a.split()
c=[i for i in b if i]
print(c)
```

Meaning:

```
b=a.split()
c=[i for i in b if i!=' ']
print(c)
```